# Add multiple suffix in s3 event notification from console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, notifications

I need event notification when files with multiple extensions like .log, .txt, etc has been added to AWS s3 bucket. Can we add multiple suffix in s3 event notification from console ?

Comment: What about the information in the [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-filtering)?

Comment: I found something like <NotificationConfiguration>  which is according to aws doc is XML in the notification subresource associated with a bucket. Since, I'm new to AWS and AWS S3, I don't have idea where should I put this XML.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create an **Event** in the Amazon S3 console, which can then trigger a Lambda function or send a message via SNS or SQS.

This configuration accepts a `prefix` (effectively a directory) and a `suffix` (eg `.jpg`).

Simply open the bucket, go to the **Properties** tab and click **Events** (down the bottom).

See: [Configuring Amazon S3 Event Notifications - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)

You can create multiple Events, each of which has a different suffix. But you can't create one Event with multiple suffixes. An alternative is to create an Event for any suffix (any file type), and have the Lambda function examine the filename and exit if it has an uninteresting suffix.

Comment: Yeah. I created event notification like the doc has explained. I just wanted to know that, can we add multiple suffix rather than just a suffix from s3 console ?


And I also found something like <NotificationConfiguration> which according to aws doc is XML in the notification subresource associated with a bucket. Since, I'm new to AWS and AWS S3, I'm not aware where should I put the XML.

Comment: You could create multiple Events, each of which has a different suffix. But you can't create one Event with multiple suffixes. An alternative is to create an Event for _any_ suffix (any file type), and have the Lambda function examine the filename and exit if it has an uninteresting suffix.

Comment: Thanks  John Rotenstein

Comment: This second comment should be the answer.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein sir, what if I want one event to trigger for `.jpg`, `.png`, or `.jpeg` but not on `.gif`? actually, I have an existing lambda that triggers image resizing  but I want to skip it for `.gif` extension now

Comment: I have to skip from lambda functions or multiple events? Other than no solutions for multiple suffix

Comment: there is a way to suppress one type of file? I mean any file except pdf

Comment: @CristianSepulveda No, it is not possible to "suppress one type of file". I would recommend that the Lambda function accepts ALL files, and then it can filter the file type within the function's code, like shown in NineCattoRules' answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Lambda` with an `S3` trigger to your bucket and edit the function code to check for the file type.

Eg. for `Node JS` use something like this:

```
  // Check that the file type is supported
  const fileType = typeMatch[1].toLowerCase();
  if (fileType != "txt" && fileType != "pdf") {
      console.log(`Unsupported file type: ${fileType}`);
      return;
  }
```

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html#with-s3-tutorial-create-function-code)

Comment: Ideally you'd want to use the trigger to do this filtering rather than having loads of unnecessary lambda executions.

Comment: @HarryJones Please post your answer, because without Lambda I can't even imagine how you can do it.